# Calculating difference between value and (moving) average in InfluxQL

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxql

I'm tracking the performance of a wireless network and need to protocol when it is better or worse than expected. To protocol this I want a Grafana dashboard where the measured values (every 2 hours) are compared to the average measured previously (either moving or over the whole series).

I have tried many different combinations of sub-queries and the like, all not resulting in a working system. I have also tried inner joins (but these were removed?).

### Wanted State

This is the closest to what would be desired, and the closest to "should work":

```
SELECT last("sum") / moving_average("sum", 72) * 100 FROM (
    SELECT "metadata_gateways_0_rssi" + "metadata_gateways_0_snr" AS "sum"
    FROM "ip6-test-7" WHERE $timeFilter
) GROUP BY "payload_fields_location", time($__interval)
fill(previous)
```

This doesn't work even if `moving_average(mean("sum"), 72)` is used, actually using the ["advanced syntax"](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#advanced-syntax-16) doesn't work at all for me.

### Current State

Works but isn't really what is needed:

```
SELECT last("sum") / mean("sum") * 100 FROM (
    SELECT "metadata_gateways_0_rssi" + "metadata_gateways_0_snr" AS "sum" 
    FROM "ip6-test-7" WHERE $timeFilter
) GROUP BY "payload_fields_location", time(1d)
fill(previous)
```

Having $__interval as 2h results in the series always being 100 (obviously).

### Relevant Github Issue

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/14452